# Compare out parameter before initialization it

Tags: c#, out

I try to compare string variable with string - out parameter and it isn't compiled .
It's seem it wait to initialization before compare but i can't change the value before .

```
public bool DownloadZipFile(out string zipUrl)
{
        string zip = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText();
        // my code ...

        if (zipUrl != string.Empty && zipUrl == zip)
            Assert.Fail("Copy Zip Url : zip url not updated . zip url equal to prev zip url");

        zipUrl = zip;
        return true;
}
```

When I build the proj I get :

> Error 2   Use of unassigned out parameter 'zipUrl'

Comment: Use ref parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`out` parameters are expected to be passed into method as `uninitialized` references and `initialized` before leaving the function. Given that, in your code you are trying to compare an uninitialized variable, thats why you get compilation error.

Could you try with `ref`?